# syntax error in test complete VBScript

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, testcomplete

I am new to test complete I am trying to use a generic method to create script but I am not able to combine browser and element

```
Function EditText (BrowserObject,EditboxName, EditValue)
 BrowserObject.EditboxName.SetText EditValue
End Function
```

but the standard script like `Aliases.browser.WebOrders2.ctl00MainContentfmwOrdertxt.SetText EditValue`
 is working fine.

When I run the script It is showing `Waiting for EditboxName`  I tried `object.TextBox(EditboxName)` but not working Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Editbox` in your example is a parameter that works like a variable. It is impossible to use a variable value as a call to a method or property in this way:

`BrowserObject.EditboxName`

This is a call to the `EditBoxName` property or method that definitely does not exist in this situation.

I think that the best way you can do is search for an object using the [`FindChild`](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/test-objects/members/common-for-all/findchild-method.html) method. You will need to use a good identification property in this call to reference an object. For example:

```
Set tBox = BrowserObject.FindChild("NativeWebObject.id", EditBoxName, 15)
If tBox.Exist Then
  tBox.SetText EditValue
Else
  Log.Error "The " & EditBoxName & " object is not found"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much .... we have webedit(xxxxx) option in uft  like that, in test complete we don't have any method ?

Comment: TestComplete does not have a method with such minor feature. However, TC has many more general ways to address and find an object. The FindChild method is just one of them.